# How function is getting called from for_each() without argument

Tags: c++, c++11

I have done few code in C++98, but I am stuck on one problem where I saw a function is getting called from a `for_each()` loop, and that function definition has an argument, but while calling we are not passing any arguments to it.

Below is the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void print_square(int i)
{
 cout << i*i << endl; // here i value should be garbage
}

int main()
{
 vector<int> v;
 // vector gets filled
 for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), print_square); //print_square is called 
 return 0;
}
```

Why is the compiler not giving an error here? How am I getting the vector values printed?

Comment: `but while calling we are not passing any arguments.` You are not _calling_ the function.

Comment: Because `for_each` is calling the function with the argument. You’re just telling it which function to call.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, but function is with argument , So  while specifying inside the forloop it sud be with argument

Comment: @tkausl, if function is not getting called then while compiling it sud search for that identifier and gives compiler error

Comment: You appear to have misunderstood what the code shown is actually doing.  Please see the documentation regarding [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) -- it provides a possible implementation that might prove informative.

Comment: @TuhinPanda Read up about **function pointers**. You are actually passing the *address* of `print_square()` to `for_each()`, which uses that address to actually *call* `print_square()` with an argument on each loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You have two misconceptions about the *expression* `for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), print_square)`

1. It is not a loop.
2. It doesn't contain a call to `print_square`.

It is merely a function call to an instantiation of the `for_each` function template. That function accepts `print_square` as an argument. Now, *inside the function*, there will very likely be a loop and a call to `print_square` (with arguments). That is why you see output.

Answer (score 1):

> why compiler is not giving error here

Because you pass a function pointer as intended (more general a *callable expression*).

The expansion of the `for_each()` template will call the specified callable expression with the argument retrieved from the sequence you specify, basically that expands to:

```
for(auto x = v.begin(); x != v.end(); ++x)
     print_square(*x);
               // ^^ Here's where the parameter is actually passed
```